# am getting this error while starting spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I updated spyder to 4.0.1 and received this error and i also downgraded spyder to 3.7 but still it's not working

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
                  File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3285, *in main*
               mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
        File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3140, in run_spyder
        main.setup()
        File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 914, in setup
              from spyder.plugins.ipythonconsole import IPythonConsole
        File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole.py", line 25, in 
              from jupyter_client.connect import find_connection_file
        File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in 
        from  .connect import *
        File "C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 35, *in 
       from jupyter_core.paths import jupyter_data_dir, jupyter_runtime_dir, secure_write*

    ImportError: cannot import name 'secure_write' from 'jupyter_core.paths' 
                     (C:\Users\Lazxy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py)
```

Comment: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5014#issuecomment-547762322

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`conda update jupyter_core`

Comment: I edited your answer with the right command (conda instead of pip) and the right package (jupyter_core instead of jupyter_client).